# When does code belong in the model in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Currently putting in a lot of rails 3 practice and I was working on an authentication system and was following a tutorial on railscasts. Ryan from railscasts done a sort of update to that tutorial with some minor changes to take advantage of rails 3.1

e.g. has_secure_password

So some of the code in my Sessions_controller changed to:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged In"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid Credentials"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path, :notice =>"Logged Out"
  end

end
```

What I would like to know is if some of the code in the create method/action should be in the model? Is it good or bad practice to have this code there?

What rules should I be following as I want to learn the correct way and not pick up bad habits because I've gone past that part of learning a framework where things start to make sense much more usually than they don't.

Advice is appreciate..

What I would like to know in particular is..
1. When does a programmer know when code belongs in the model? How does he/she make that decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the most important questions in OO programming.

It's all about responsibilities. Place code in your model if you think that model is responsible for that piece of functionality.

In your example you see that:

- The `SessionController` is only responsible creating and destroying the the user's session.
- The `User` is responsible for authentication.

All business logic goes into your models. Your controllers takes care of populating your views, handling the user's input and sending the user on their way. View simply display information, hardly contain any logic (if any).

Also: take a look at existing projects for inspiration (for example, [Shopify](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app)).

Answer (score 0):

My advice:

In User model (pseudocode):

```
function authenticate(username, pass) {
  /*get user by name
  return user_id (or user object if you need some user data in view) if auth ok,   otherwise false
  */
}
```

I think you should always keep controllers small as possible.
The most important think in OOP is encapsulation so you should write all operation on user in user class, return to client code (in this case controller) only what controller need to do his job - add user id to session.